# duality gap of LASSO -- the idea behind residual rescaling

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I'm reading through [this paper](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/l1_ls.pdf), where they find the dual of LASSO and then find a lower bound of the optimal solution of LASSO. Let $p^*, q^*$ be the optimal solution of LASSO and its dual consequently. Let us call the dual problem $G(\nu)$, we know that $G(\nu)<p^*$. To find the duality gap (i.e., the sub-optimal) we need to find the tightest bound (i.e., the maximum value of $G(\nu),\nu$ is a dual feasible). However, the authors pick a $\nu$ that, from my understanding, is not the optimal value of $G(\nu)$. Although it is simple to calculate, I think it is not understandable heuristic. The following screenshot shows it (taken from the top of the right column in page 4). I have tried to find a closed form solution of the dual problem but what I got is not even close to this. What is the intuition behind such a heuristic? (in case it is indeed a heuristic.)

*Edit*: This heuristic is called residual rescaling but I was not able to find the original paper that proposed it. So, I am asking about the intuition behind it?

[image]

Comment: being fast to compute might be its only feat, why do you think there is more to it?

Comment: @LinAlg my understanding that the duality gap must be calculated on the optimal solution of the dual not *any* dual feasible point. The duality gap using such approach might be too liberal. e.g., using this approach, the duality gap might be 100 but in fact it is  .0001.

Comment: You have a good understanding of the issue, but sometimes it's better to quickly report the 100 than to take a long time and compute the 0.0001. I do not think the authors claim that they provide the best dual bound, merely 'an easily computed bound on the suboptimality'.

Comment: @LinAlg I see, thanks. Their (and others) were not explicit about this issue though :(